# What is the meaning of multiple occurrences of the same network/object in tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am wondering how multiple occurrences of the same network/object in tensorboard must be interpreted. [image]

If I look at this example of a graph with two networks the generator and the discriminator. I see both of the networks multiple times with suffices "_1" "_2" and so on. The intention of this is to have exactly one generator and one discriminator.

My question is, whether there is something wrong and multiple networks with independent weights have been generated or are these nodes simply references to the same instance i.e. identical values in the variables? Here is my graph:

```
def discriminator(x, batch_size, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('discriminator') as scope:
        if (reuse):
            tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()

        s = 2
        f = 3

        n_ch1 = 3
        w = init_weights('d_wc1', [f, f, CHANNELS, n_ch1])
        b = init_bias('d_bc1', [n_ch1])
        h = conv2d(x, w, s, b)
        h = bn(h, 'd_bn1')
        h = tf.nn.relu(h)
        h = tf.nn.dropout(h, 0.9)

        n_ch2 = 3
        w = init_weights('d_wc2', [f, f, n_ch1, n_ch2])
        b = init_bias('d_bc2', [n_ch2])
        h = conv2d(h, w, s, b) 
        h = bn(h, 'd_bn2')
        h = tf.nn.relu(h)

        dimensions = n_ch2*HEIGHT*WIDTH//s**4 
        w = init_weights('d_w1', [dimensions, 1])
        b = init_bias('d_b1', [1])
        h_flat = tf.reshape(h, [-1, dimensions])
        output = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h_flat, w) + b)

    return output


def generator(x, batch_size, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('generator') as scope:
        if (reuse):
            tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()

        s = 1
        f = 1 
        keep_prob = 0.9
        blow_up_factor = 2
        output_shape = [batch_size, blow_up_factor*HEIGHT, 
                        blow_up_factor*WIDTH, CHANNELS]
        w = init_weights('g_wdc0', [f, f, CHANNELS, CHANNELS])
        b = init_bias('g_bdc0', [CHANNELS])
        h = deconv2d(x, w, blow_up_factor, b, output_shape)        
        h = bn(h, "g_bnd0")                
        h = tf.nn.relu(h)
        h = tf.nn.dropout(h, keep_prob)

        h = avg_pool(h, blow_up_factor, 1)

        w = init_weights('g_wc0', [f, f, CHANNELS, CHANNELS])
        b = init_bias('g_bc0', [CHANNELS])
        h = conv2d(h, w, blow_up_factor, b)
        h = bn(h, 'g_bn0')
        h = tf.nn.relu(h)        
        h = tf.nn.dropout(h, keep_prob)
        h = h + x

        n_ch1 = 32
        w = init_weights('g_wc1', [f, f, CHANNELS, n_ch1])
        b = init_bias('g_bc1', [n_ch1])
        h = conv2d(h, w, s, b)
        h = bn(h, 'g_bn1')
        h = tf.nn.relu(h)
        h = tf.nn.dropout(h, keep_prob)

        n_ch2 = 128
        w = init_weights('g_wc2', [f, f, n_ch1, n_ch2])
        b = init_bias('g_bc2', [n_ch2])
        h = conv2d(h, w, s, b)
        h = bn(h, "g_bn2")                
        h = tf.nn.relu(h)
        h = tf.nn.dropout(h, keep_prob)

        n_ch3 = 128
        w = init_weights('g_wc3', [f, f, n_ch3, n_ch2])
        b = init_bias('g_bc3', [n_ch3])
        h = conv2d(h, w, 1, b)
        h = bn(h, "g_bn3")                
        h = tf.nn.relu(h)        
        h = tf.nn.dropout(h, keep_prob)

        output_shape = [batch_size, HEIGHT//s, WIDTH//s, n_ch1]
        w = init_weights('g_wdc2', [f, f, n_ch1, n_ch3])
        b = init_bias('g_bdc2', [n_ch1])
        h = deconv2d(h, w, s, b, output_shape)        
        h = bn(h, "g_bnd2")                
        h = tf.nn.relu(h)

        output_shape = [batch_size, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS]
        w = init_weights('g_wdc1', [f, f, CHANNELS, n_ch1])
        b = init_bias('g_bdc1', [CHANNELS])
        output = deconv2d(h, w, s, b, output_shape)

    return tf.nn.sigmoid(output+x)

logs_path = logdir()  
output_frequency = 500  
batch_size = 4
iterations = 10005
norm_weight = 0.0
learning_rate = 0.0001

with tf.variable_scope('Rainy_batch'):
    rainy_image_batch = image_batch('./rainy/*.jpeg')
with tf.variable_scope('Sunny_batch'):    
    sunny_image_batch = image_batch('./sunny/*.jpeg')
with tf.variable_scope('Test_batch'):
    rainy_test_batch = image_batch('./test/*.jpeg')

x_placeholder = tf.placeholder("float", shape = [None, WIDTH, HEIGHT, CHANNELS], name='Rainy') 
y_placeholder = tf.placeholder("float", shape = [None, WIDTH, HEIGHT, CHANNELS], name='Sunny')

Dy = discriminator(y_placeholder, batch_size)  # discriminator prediction probabilities for sunny images
Gx = generator(x_placeholder, batch_size, reuse=False)  # generated images
Dg = discriminator(Gx, batch_size, reuse=True)  # discriminator prediction probabilities for generated images

d_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(Dy) + tf.log(1. - Dg))
g_loss_logit = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(Dg))
g_loss_norm = norm_weight * tf.norm( (Gx - x_placeholder), 1)
g_loss =  g_loss_logit + g_loss_norm

tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
d_vars = [var for var in tvars if 'd_' in var.name]
g_vars = [var for var in tvars if 'g_' in var.name]

tf.summary.scalar('gLoss', g_loss)
tf.summary.scalar('dLoss', d_loss)

adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)

with tf.variable_scope('discriminator') as scope:
    trainerD = adam.minimize(d_loss, var_list=d_vars)

with tf.variable_scope('generator') as scope:   
    trainerG = adam.minimize(g_loss, var_list=g_vars)
```

[Full notebook](https://github.com/soerendip/RainyGANs/blob/master/GAN.ipynb)

Comment: Can you include your code for this?  It's possible that you're declaring or restoring components within a loop; TensorFlow will append _1, _2, etc in such cases so that everything has a unique identifier.

Comment: I added some example code.